# How to update Django endless pagination content list with new content with ajax response data

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-endless-pagination

I am trying to update my page based on user search query. I am able to get the search results from the server but how do i update my `contextList`. I have also implemented Django endless pagination but how do i reload the list with new content

views.py

```
import json
import traceback
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context,loader
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from eScraperInterfaceApp.eScraperUtils import eScraperUtils 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def renderError(message):
    """
        This function displays error message
    """    
    t = loader.get_template("error.html")                
    c = Context({ 'Message':message})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))


def index(request,template = 'index.html',
                  page_template = 'index_page.html' ):
    """
        This function handles request for index page 
    """

    try:        
        context = {}
        contextList = []
        utilsOBJ = eScraperUtils()        
        q = {"size" : 300000,
             "query" :{ "match_all" : { "boost" : 1.2 }}}
        results = utilsOBJ.search(q)       

        for i in results['hits']['hits']:

            contextDict = i['_source']            
            contextDict['image_paths'] = json.loads(contextDict['image_paths'])
            contextList.append(contextDict)            

        context.update({'contextList':contextList,'page_template': page_template})     

        if request.is_ajax():    # override the template and use the 'page' style instead.
            template = page_template

        return render_to_response(
            template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )

    except :        
        return renderError('%s' % (traceback.format_exc()))

def search (request,template = 'index.html',
                  page_template = 'index_page.html' ):

    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':        

            context = {}
            contextList = []
            keyWord = request.POST['keyWord']
            print keyWord   
            utilsOBJ = eScraperUtils()
            results = utilsOBJ.search('productCategory:%(keyWord)s or productSubCategory:%(keyWord)s or productDesc:%(keyWord)s' % {'keyWord' : keyWord})
            for i in results['hits']['hits']:
                contextDict = i['_source']
                contextDict['image_paths'] = json.loads(contextDict['image_paths'])   
                contextList.append(contextDict)            

            if request.is_ajax():    # override the template and use the 'page' style instead.
                template = page_template

            context.update({'contextList':contextList,'page_template': page_template})                           
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), mimetype='application/json')
    except :        
        return renderError('%s' % (traceback.format_exc()))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fashion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="query" type="text" />
    <input id="search-submit" type="button" value="Search" />    
</form>

<div class="product_container">
    <ul class="product_list">
        <div class="endless_page_template">
            {% include page_template %}
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="product_container">
    <ul class="product_list">
        <div class="endless_page_template">
            {% include page_template %}
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>


{% block js %}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="static/js/endless_on_scroll.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>    
<script>
    $.endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: true,
    endless_on_scroll_margin : 10,
    paginateOnScrollChunkSize: 5
});</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#search-submit").click(function() {

    // Get the query string from the text field
    var query = $("#query").val();
    alert(query);    
    data = { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'keyWord' : query};
    // Retrieve a page from the server and insert its contents
    // into the selected document.    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/search/',
    data: data,   
    success: function(context){
        var items = [];
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context));
        console.log(jsonData['contextList']);
        $.each(jsonData['contextList'], function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });
        $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'product_list',
        html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
        },
    error: function( error ){
        alert( error );
      },
    dataType: 'json',
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

index_page.html :

```
{% load endless %}
{% paginate 10 contextList %}
{% for item in contextList %}
    <li >
        <a href="{{ item.productURL }}" ><img src="/images/{{ item.image_paths.0 }}/" height="100" width="100" border='1px solid'/></a>
        <br>
        <span class="price">
        <span class="mrp">MRP : {{ item.productMRP}}</span>
        {% if item.productPrice %}<br>
        <span class="discounted_price">Offer Price : {{ item.productPrice}}</span>
        {%endif%}
        </span>
    </li>  
{% endfor %}

{% show_more "even more" "working" %}
```

can someone please tell me how to reload `contextList` with new data....

Comment: This is the exact same question you asked just a while ago and you've accepted my answer. If you didn't understand it, is there something more I can explain to help you?

Comment: No , I am trying to pass new list to the index_page.html to reload the data into list

Comment: As i am using endless scrolling .. How do i reload the list in index_page.html

Comment: Allright, and as I described earlier, using approach number two from my previous answer would be beneficial for you :)

Comment: I tried that solution but it doesn't worked ......

Comment: Did you copy and paste it exactly because that wont work for you.

Comment: updated the code above

Comment: Just looking through the docs, you're missing the decorator `@page_template()` on your views

Comment: tried that too .... And the output is http://screencloud.net/v/y2MO

Comment: New `JSON` object at the end but i want only response data in the list not append the data to the list

Comment: HTML code http://notepad.cc/lesluzzi96 after adding new content to the list